# ¿Por qué la sentencia no me indica un error en una condicional de SQL Server?

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo una tabla que contiene una columna de tipo `varchar`, pero cuando lo comparo con un tipo `int` con la expresión `CASE`, la sentencia no me arroja ningún error.

```
create table tabla (
    valor varchar(1)
)

insert into tabla values ('1'), ('a')

select
    case when ISNULL(valor, '') = 1 then 'r' else 'r' end
from tabla
```

Pero cuando cambio la sentencia por:

```
select
    case when ISNULL(valor, '') = 1 then 'r' else 'R' end
from tabla
```

Recién me arroja el error de conversión:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.

- [Ejemplo en sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4815/1)

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Realicé una búsqueda por la red y no encuentro nada de documentación al respecto pero lo que me indica la lógica es que cuando el `THEN result_expression` y el `ELSE else_result_expression` son iguales (en este caso `then 'r' else 'r'`), el manejador no se mete en líos y siempre escogerá al primero, por eso no te marca error, en cambio, cuando son diferentes es cuando realiza la validación y es cuando vota el error del casteo. Seguiré buscando documentación oficial al respecto.

Answer (score 2):

Realice las siguientes pruebas:

```
select
    case when ISNULL(valor, '') = 1 then 's' else 'r' end
from tabla
```

> La consulta anterior arroja el mismo error

```
select
    case when ISNULL(valor, '') = 1 then 'T' else 'T' end
from tabla
```

> Está consulta no da error y presenta el resutado 'T', 'T'

Esto me lleva a sacar la conclusión que cuando en la instrucción `CASE` la respuesta va a ser la misma independientemente del resultado de la expresión `WHEN`, entonces SQL toma la decisión de no evaluar la expresión y simplemente arroja el resultado que para este caso va a ser el mismo en todos los registros.

Ahora bien cuando el resultado puede ser distinto, entonces SQL debe evaluar la expresión del `WHEN`, y es en este momento que se genera el error cuando se intenta evaluar `'a' = 1` en el segundo registro del ejemplo.

Comment: Muy lógico. Sería interesante ver si hay alguna documentación al respecto, pero lo dudo mucho. Por lo que esto debería considerarse como una optimización que puede cambiar de una versión de SQL Server a otra.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sencilla al ser un query se puede optimizar el resultado ya que el resultado es Deterministico

Aun que no tenemos el codigo de sql server podemos deducir

Si ejecutamos lo siguiente

```
select case when 'a' = 1 then 'r' else 'r' end
```

este Fallara ya que esta es un statement sin query

Pero si esta misma la incluimos en

```
 select * from
 (select case when 'a' = 1 then 'r' else 'r' end as a 
 )data
```

este si se procesara ya que al ser un query el optimizador es suficientemente inteligente para no procesar el when

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

Creo que tiene que ver mas con la comparación en el when. Recuerda que esta comparando varchar

ISNULL(valor, '') = '1'

Comment: Ya sé que el error de conversión ocurre por la `prioridad de tipo`, mi pregunta es el por qué no ocurre un error en la 1era sentencia.